# Scrapy image is distorted

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been using scrapy to crawl a web site and download jpegs every couple months. Today, when I crawled the site, I noticed my images were really distorted, but when I go to the URL of the image, the image is not distorted. I'm pretty sure my code is correct, and I've tried it on another website and the problem persists.

Here's what the distortion looks like, the lower half with the text is offset and discolored:
[image: This was crawled from: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s5Bo.jpg]

This came from crawling https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IsK1.jpg and using an xpath to find https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s5Bo.jpg.

Spider (example.py):

```
import scrapy
from test.items import TestItem
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["imgur.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IsK1.jpg',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = TestItem()
        item['img_url'] = response.xpath('//link[@rel="image_src"]/@href').extract()
        return item
```

I send the jpeg URL to a simple image pipeline (pipelines.py):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
class TestPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
        def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
            image_url = item['img_url'][0]
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    img_url = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'test'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['test.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'test.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'test.pipelines.TestPipeline': 1
}
IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/brian/Projects/nb/test'
```

The only thing I can think of that has changed since I last used it was that I reinstalled anaconda which probably updated scrapy and any dependencies. I'm running scrapy v1.1.1 with python 2.7.12.

I ran the code on a different computer that has scrapy 1.0.3 and it downloads images correctly. I then installed scrapy 1.0.3 on the problem computer in a conda environment with just scrapy and its dependencies but the image still comes out distorted.

Comment: I don't think scrapy can actually distort the image since all it does it takes bytes it receives in response body and writes them to file. What's the python version your scrapy runs on? Could be issue with python3. Also it could be imgur's fault here.

Comment: Try to give us a [mcve].

Comment: @Granitosaurus I'm running python 2.7.12 and I've tried it on two different sites and the same problem happens. The docs mention that scrapy uses PIL/Pillow for image processing and I've tried installing/uninstalling them but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried not using the images pipeline, and simply storing the image from the response (response.body) to a file, to see if you can reproduce the problem when doing that?

Comment: @Gallaecio this problem came and went without any changes on my end. I never figured out the cause.